# Headful mode not enabled in puppeteer in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ubuntu, puppeteer, google-chrome-os

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 22.o4 on a chromebook. I want to use puppeteer with node. I installed it with npm and ran the following test:

```
//adding Puppeteer library
const pt = require('puppeteer');
pt.launch({headless: 'false'}).then(async browser => {
//browser new page
const p = await browser.newPage();
//set viewpoint of browser page
await p.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 500 })
//launch URL
await p.goto('https://bstackdemo.com')
//capture screenshot
await p.screenshot({
path: 'browserstack-demo.png'
});
//browser close
await browser.close()
})
```

There are no errors and the expected output (screenshot) is produced, but I don't see the browser, even passing the {headless: 'false'} object. How can I get puppeteer into headful mode?

Comment: Hi, can you please try to follow the documentation https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/puppeteer, most probably the example they share here runs in headfull mode . Hence you can try running that take take code reference. If still that does not work raise an issue at support@browserstack.com